# role of super user in community

Tags: community

In Lightning Community, whats super user? How to query super user in salesforce.

Anyone Please expain me,whats the role of super user in buisness point of view

I checked below documention:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_super_user_access.htm&type=5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of Super User in Community,

> You can grant super user access to anyone with a Partner Community or a Customer Community Plus license.
>
> Granting super user access to external users in your community lets them access more data and records, regardless of sharing rules and organization-wide defaults. Super users can access data owned by other partner users who have the same role or a role below them. Super user access applies to cases, leads, custom objects, and opportunities only. External users have access to these objects only if you expose them using profiles or sharing and add the tabs to the community.

Business scenario is: Partners want compare among themselves as how many Opportunities and revenues they have achieved throughout this year.

It's basically peer-to-peer comparison.

*You can think of similar kind of scenario when we configure Dynamic Dashboard where dashboard can be run by a specified users who has higher visibility of data.*

Comment: How to identify super user in community?

Comment: check this: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_partner_super_user_access.htm&type=5

Comment: can you please explain line with some examplein your answer:  Super users have access to data owned by other partner users belonging to the same account who have the same role or a role below them in the role hierarchy.

Comment: You can configure at your sandbox or DE and let me know where you need more info